# How can using user defined function in custom data validation?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In my `Worksheet` I have a `Table` and want to define `Data validation` for a column that contained the date, as bellow:

```
=S2M(B2)<>"Error"
```

In above, `S2M()` is a user defined function for converting date from `Persian date` to `Gregorian date`, because checking input date is right.

But excel is not letting me use user defined functions in Custom `Data validation`.

This error shows: A named range you specified cannot be found.

Please note that I was using bellow code in `Custom Data validation` and that works, right.

```
=AND(LEN(B2)=10;ISNUMBER(IFERROR(VALUE(MATCH(VALUE(MID(B2;1;4));INDIRECT("intTable[Year]");0)&MATCH(MID(B2;6;2);INDIRECT("intTable[Mounth]");0)&MATCH(MID(B2;9;2);INDIRECT("intTable[Day]");0));FALSE)))
```

Explain is a Persian date example: 1396/05/25

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't, see this post bellow: https://superuser.com/questions/797053/use-an-user-defined-function-for-data-validation

Comment: I don't know, maybe the guy who down-vote think you did not make enough researches ...

Comment: Upvoted as the question is both reasonable and clear to me. :)

Comment: Above answer not cover my question. That answer is: **The user-defined function must return a Range not an array of value.** and in above, my user defined function returns not an array of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Select B2, or whichever cell in row 2 you want the validation to apply to. Now define a name called, say, IsValid, using:

```
=S2M(B2)<>"Error"
```

Now in the data validation box, all you need to enter is:

```
=IsValid
```

in the source box and make sure to uncheck the Ignore Blank option.

Comment: Problem. I want apply the validation for the column of a Table. But when using above, `IsValid` "Refer to" code, not extend from B1 to B2 and ... for each column cell of respective Table. This way works only for single cell, that defined in `S2M(B2)<>"Error"`

Comment: No, if you entered it as specified, it will adjust for each row.

Comment: Greatly thanks. That would be awesome. May I remove above comment, or its better to stay?

Comment: Why `Ignore blank` should be uncheck? That is an important point. Whats the reason of unchecking that, related to this?

Comment: I don't mind either way. If you don't uncheck it, it won't work. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Where did you know and get this point? How you found unchecking `Ignore blank` is related?

Comment: I've been doing this for quite a long time.

Comment: Please teach Us how did you get this point? I ask this, because reaching your logic of problem solving. (point of should unchecking `Ignore blank`) I think about why this related to this issue? Or why you said this is a bug and How you think this is a bug, Of course before these, how you get that: should unchecking `ignore blank` for working this.

Comment: Question: I want this `Refer to` field of `Name`, get change and extend automatically when `Work Sheet` changes. I have several `Work Sheets` and need use above validation in each columns `Table` that contains date. In may above name extend and change automatically in each `Work Sheet` of I should defining several `Names` for each worksheet?

Comment: My point is that I came across that so long ago, that I don't recall how. It's a bug because the two should not be related. Re your follow up, I don't understand the question. You can define an identical name locally to each sheet if that's what you mean.

Comment: The `Refer to` field of above `Name`, automatically change to this: `=S2M(Sheet1!B2)<>"Error"` and only works in appropriated Worksheet. This Name extend and works truly in each cells of the sheet, that Name was defined first time. but Name formula change as above and in another sheets, been sheet name `sheet1!` is constant, and cell address, extending.

Comment: I know but you can define a name for each worksheet with the appropriate reference.

Comment: Is it possible that name reference automatically changes in another sheets? because I want my Names count been limited, and I have many sheets. May I adding only one name, for all sheets?

Comment: I have about 7 sheets. I should Add and define 7 Names, with same appropriate reference? This case, is confuser that using 1 name.

Comment: You could just use one name and define it as: `=S2M(INDIRECT("RC",0))<>"Error"`

Comment: Fantastic! Awesome. Thank you with great regard. I Ask this issue (A name for all sheets). Please answer in my new related question. This answer was awesome. Thanks.

Comment: A combination of this answer and this one helped me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470396/vba-data-validation-with-user-defined-function