# How can defining global reference for a Name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want Using a `Name` in sheets with bellow reference.

```
=S2M(B2)<>"Error"
```

Name: `IsValid`

This reference only works where in the sheet that defined at first.

But I what change its appropriated reference to one, that been globally work in all sheets with same name.

How can I do that?

Comment: I should share its module and Comment has not needed space. I'm ready share this date convert module as question of the appropriated answer.

Comment: Either the scope is `Workbook` and `Refer to` is `Sheet1!A1` (For example). (RC) In the same sheet when the `Name` call from another cell, its `Refer to` changes to appropriate sheet reference. But when it call in another `Work Sheet`, `Sheet1!` is absolutely constant and not change. I need changing above formula for `Name` reference been related when `Work Sheet` has change. `S2M` is my user defined function that wrote in `VBA` for changing date. Please visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710157/how-can-using-user-defined-function-in-custom-data-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=S2M(INDIRECT("RC",0))<>"Error"
```